# How to enforce the user to click a checkbox in profile section in Buddypress

Tags: php, wordpress, checkbox, buddypress

I'm currently developping a website using wordpress & buddypress. My aim is to display a checkbox in the profile page which consist in accepting the "term of use". This point is ok. But I would like to enforce the user to  thick this checkbox, otherwise he can leave the page (or validate the changes). The option "obligatory" of "required filed" in the wp-admin section (Users > profile configuration) is not efficient.

Do you have any suggestion, or advice to give ?

Thank you

Comment: You can use the following plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/bp-force-profile/

Answer (score 0):

How strongly do you want to enforce this? If the member **must** agree to the terms no matter what, you could do a simple redirect to their profile page if the terms are yet to be agreed

```
function redirect_to_terms() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $terms_not_agreed ) {
        bp_core_add_message( 'You must agree to our terms', 'error' );
        wp_redirect( '/members/' . bp_core_get_username( bp_loggedin_user_id() ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_terms' );
```

**Note:** You'll need to assign either `true` or `false` to `$terms_not_agreed` earlier in your code.

Comment: Thank you @henrywright for your answer. Indeed, the user must thick the checkbox to be able to use the website (when he connects for the first time, he is automaticly redirect to his profile page). I will try to implement and adapt this code to mine for now.